# Default example.bib of MastersDoctoralThesis on Overleaf won't compile

Tags: bibtex

The following TeX code says

> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 298.

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
       ]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

    \usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default

    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

    \addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

    \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    \end{document}
```

Neither the `.bib` of my own nor the `example.bib` MastersDoctoralThesis on Overleaf that I'm trying to compile works. In the following is the default one:

```
  @article{Reference1,
    Abstract = {We have developed an enhanced Littrow configuration extended cavity diode laser (ECDL) that can be tuned without changing the direction of the output beam. The output of a conventional Littrow ECDL is reflected from a plane mirror fixed parallel to the tuning diffraction grating. Using a free-space Michelson wavemeter to measure the laser wavelength, we can tune the laser over a range greater than 10 nm without any alteration of alignment.},
    Author = {C. J. Hawthorn and K. P. Weber and R. E. Scholten},
    Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
    Month = {12},
    Number = {12},
    Numpages = {3},
    Pages = {4477--4479},
    Title = {Littrow Configuration Tunable External Cavity Diode Laser with Fixed Direction Output Beam},
    Volume = {72},
    Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/72/4477/1},
    Year = {2001}}

@article{Reference3,
    Abstract = {Operating a laser diode in an extended cavity which provides frequency-selective feedback is a very effective method of reducing the laser's linewidth and improving its tunability. We have developed an extremely simple laser of this type, built from inexpensive commercial components with only a few minor modifications. A 780~nm laser built to this design has an output power of 80~mW, a linewidth of 350~kHz, and it has been continuously locked to a Doppler-free rubidium transition for several days.},
    Author = {A. S. Arnold and J. S. Wilson and M. G. Boshier and J. Smith},
    Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
    Month = {3},
    Number = {3},
    Numpages = {4},
    Pages = {1236--1239},
    Title = {A Simple Extended-Cavity Diode Laser},
    Volume = {69},
    Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/69/1236/1},
    Year = {1998}}

@article{Reference2,
    Abstract = {We present a review of the use of diode lasers in atomic physics with an extensive list of references. We discuss the relevant characteristics of diode lasers and explain how to purchase and use them. We also review the various techniques that have been used to control and narrow the spectral outputs of diode lasers. Finally we present a number of examples illustrating the use of diode lasers in atomic physics experiments. Review of Scientific Instruments is copyrighted by The American Institute of Physics.},
    Author = {Carl E. Wieman and Leo Hollberg},
    Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
    Keywords = {Diode Laser},
    Month = {1},
    Number = {1},
    Numpages = {20},
    Pages = {1--20},
    Title = {Using Diode Lasers for Atomic Physics},
    Volume = {62},
    Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/62/1/1},
    Year = {1991}}
```

It'd be swell if you guys could help!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Why didn't you keep the copyright information and the freakin link so people are actually abe to help you?  Does it work with the unmodified template?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you code has some errors, for example is a `\begin{document}` missing ...

I changed the order of the used packages, important changes I marked with `<=====`

Please see (and study) the following MWE (package `filecontents` is used to have bib file and TeX file in one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Reference1,
  Abstract = {We have developed an enhanced Littrow configuration extended cavity diode laser (ECDL) that can be tuned without changing the direction of the output beam. The output of a conventional Littrow ECDL is reflected from a plane mirror fixed parallel to the tuning diffraction grating. Using a free-space Michelson wavemeter to measure the laser wavelength, we can tune the laser over a range greater than 10 nm without any alteration of alignment.},
  Author = {C. J. Hawthorn and K. P. Weber and R. E. Scholten},
  Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
  Month = {12},
  Number = {12},
  Numpages = {3},
  Pages = {4477--4479},
  Title = {Littrow Configuration Tunable External Cavity Diode Laser with Fixed Direction Output Beam},
  Volume = {72},
  Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/72/4477/1},
  Year = {2001},
}
@article{Reference3,
    Abstract = {Operating a laser diode in an extended cavity which provides frequency-selective feedback is a very effective method of reducing the laser's linewidth and improving its tunability. We have developed an extremely simple laser of this type, built from inexpensive commercial components with only a few minor modifications. A 780~nm laser built to this design has an output power of 80~mW, a linewidth of 350~kHz, and it has been continuously locked to a Doppler-free rubidium transition for several days.},
    Author = {A. S. Arnold and J. S. Wilson and M. G. Boshier and J. Smith},
    Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
    Month = {3},
    Number = {3},
    Numpages = {4},
    Pages = {1236--1239},
    Title = {A Simple Extended-Cavity Diode Laser},
    Volume = {69},
    Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/69/1236/1},
    Year = {1998},
}
@article{Reference2,
    Abstract = {We present a review of the use of diode lasers in atomic physics with an extensive list of references. We discuss the relevant characteristics of diode lasers and explain how to purchase and use them. We also review the various techniques that have been used to control and narrow the spectral outputs of diode lasers. Finally we present a number of examples illustrating the use of diode lasers in atomic physics experiments. Review of Scientific Instruments is copyrighted by The American Institute of Physics.},
    Author = {Carl E. Wieman and Leo Hollberg},
    Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
    Keywords = {Diode Laser},
    Month = {1},
    Number = {1},
    Numpages = {20},
    Pages = {1--20},
    Title = {Using Diode Lasers for Atomic Physics},
    Volume = {62},
    Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/62/1/1},
    Year = {1991},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[%
  11pt,
  english % <================ language =================================
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % MastersDoctoralThesis

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex,
  style=authoryear,
  natbib=true
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\begin{document} % <====================================================
text \cite{Reference2} text % <=========================================

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you so much and sorry for messing up to copy the begindocument line. As you are probably already guessing: this is my very first attempt with LaTeX.